# List populated with Scrapy is returned before actually filled

Tags: python-2.7, synchronization, web-crawler, scrapy

This involves pretty much the same code I just asked a different question about this morning, so if it looks familiar, that's because it is.

```
class LbcSubtopicSpider(scrapy.Spider):

...irrelevant/sensitive code...

    rawTranscripts = []
    rawTranslations = []

    def parse(self, response):
        rawTitles = []
        rawVideos = []
        for sel in response.xpath('//ul[1]'): #only scrape the first list

            ...irrelevant code...

            index = 0
            for sub in sel.xpath('li/ul/li/a'): #scrape the sublist items
                index += 1
                if index%2!=0: #odd numbered entries are the transcripts
                    transcriptLink = sub.xpath('@href').extract()
                    #url = response.urljoin(transcriptLink[0])
                    #yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_transcript)
                else: #even numbered entries are the translations
                    translationLink = sub.xpath('@href').extract()
                    url = response.urljoin(translationLink[0])
                    yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_translation)

        print rawTitles
        print rawVideos
        print "translations:" 
        print self.rawTranslations

    def parse_translation(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//p[not(@class)]'):
            rawTranslation = sel.xpath('text()').extract()
            rawTranslation = ''.join(rawTranslation)
            #print rawTranslation
            self.rawTranslations.append(rawTranslation)
            #print self.rawTranslations
```

My problem is that "print self.rawTranslations" in the `parse(...)` method prints nothing more than `"[]"`. This could mean one of two things: it could be resetting the list right before printing, or it could be printing before the calls to `parse_translation(...)` that populate the list from links `parse(...)` follows are finished. I'm inclined to suspect it's the latter, as I can't see any code that would reset the list, unless `"rawTranslations = []"` in the class body is run multiple times.

Worth noting is that if I uncomment the same line in `parse_translation(...)`, it will print the desired output, meaning it's extracting the text correctly and the problem seems to be unique to the main `parse(...)` method.

My attempts to resolve what I believe is a synchronization problem were pretty aimless--I just tried using an RLock object based on as many Google tutorials I could find and I'm 99% sure I misused it anyway, as the result was identical.

Comment: I've been scouring the internet in the past hour trying to better understand locks in Python, and not getting very far. The idea I have in my head is to release the lock once the last subpage visit is complete, but I've found surprisingly few examples of the syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this seems like somewhat of a hacky solution, especially since I just learned of Scrapy's request priority functionality, but here's my new code that gives the desired result:

```
class LbcVideosSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    ...code omitted...

    done = 0 #variable to keep track of subtopic iterations
    rawTranscripts = []
    rawTranslations = []

    def parse(self, response):
        #initialize containers for each field
        rawTitles = []
        rawVideos = []

        ...code omitted...

            index = 0
            query = sel.xpath('li/ul/li/a')
            for sub in query: #scrape the sublist items
                index += 1
                if index%2!=0: #odd numbered entries are the transcripts
                    transcriptLink = sub.xpath('@href').extract()
                    #url = response.urljoin(transcriptLink[0])
                    #yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_transcript)
                else: #even numbered entries are the translations
                    translationLink = sub.xpath('@href').extract()
                    url = response.urljoin(translationLink[0])
                    yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_translation, \
                        meta={'index': index/2, 'maxIndex': len(query)/2})

        print rawTitles
        print rawVideos

    def parse_translation(self, response):
        #grab meta variables
        i = response.meta['index']
        maxIndex = response.meta['maxIndex']

        #interested in p nodes without class
        query = response.xpath('//p[not(@class)]')
        for sel in query:
            rawTranslation = sel.xpath('text()').extract()
            rawTranslation = ''.join(rawTranslation) #collapse each line
            self.rawTranslations.append(rawTranslation)

            #increment number of translations done, check if finished
            self.done += 1
            print self.done
            if self.done==maxIndex:
                print self.rawTranslations
```

Basically, I just kept track of how many requests were completed and making some code conditional on a request being final. This prints the fully populated list.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are not understanding how `scrapy` really works.

Scrapy is a crawling framework, used for creating website spiders, not just for doing requests, that's the `requests` module for.

Scrapy's requests work asynchronously, when you call `yield Request(...)` you are adding requests to a stack of requests that will be executed at some point (you don't have control over it). Which means that you can't expect that some part of your code after the `yield Request(...)` will be executed at that moment. In fact, your method should always end yielding a `Request` or an `Item`.

Now from what I can see and most cases of confusion with scrapy, you want to keep populating an item you created on some method, but the information you need is on a different request.

On that case, communication is usually done with the `meta` parameter of the `Request`, something like this:

```
    ...
    yield Request(url, callback=self.second_method, meta={'item': myitem, 'moreinfo': 'moreinfo', 'foo': 'bar'})

def second_method(self, response):
    previous_meta_info = response.meta
    # I can access the previous item with `response.meta['item']`
    ...
```

Comment: I don't know how much this changes the situation, but the item I'm trying to populate wasn't created in a method, but rather as an object in the class.

Comment: It doesn't seem like the meta info is the way to do this, or at least not with how I've structured everything. The reason is that I can only yield another request from either `parse` or `parse_translation`, and neither method would be able to pass `self.rawTranslations` in its complete state. If I were to do it in `parse`, it would pass an empty list; if I were to do it in `parse_translation`, it would call my third (unwritten) method as many times as there would be list entries, rather than just once at the end. I think this does have to do with the container being outside a method.